# Check if variable exists in Stata

Tags: loops, stata

I am looking for a way to check whether a variable exists in a Stata dataset, and if not to repeatedly check variable names over a loop until I find one that exists.  I am aware of the other responses to similar questions that involve `confirm` and depend on testing the value of `_rc`.

However, if you try to use these approaches repeatedly the value of `_rc` in any given iteration of a loop is only informative of whether there has been at least one error in any prior iteration.  I wish to continue testing until there is not an error, but whenever the first attempt results in an error there is no way to tell if the second attempt also results in an error because `_rc` remains the same regardless (assuming all errors report the same code).  Is there any way to either reset `_rc` to zero manually, or to test for the existence of a variable in a less ad hoc way that doesn't involve `_rc`?

Comment: Have you seen `isvar` from SSC?  It takes a list of names that might name variables in your dataset and filters it into a list of those names that are indeed variable names and a list of the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is some misunderstanding on the working of the `capture` and `_rc` procedure.

**1.** I quote:

> ... if you try to use these approaches repeatedly the value of _rc in any
>   given iteration of a loop is only informative of whether there has
>   been at least one error in any prior iteration.

This is not correct. The value of `_rc` depends on the result of the command that immediately precedes, so it will be updated until the loop finishes.

**2.** I quote again:

> ... whenever the first attempt results in an error there is no way to tell
>   if the second attempt also results in an error ...

Also incorrect. You can tell if the second, third, etc., attempt is an error by looking at `_rc`. This is a consequence of (**1**).

An example can perhaps show this:

```
clear all 
set more off

sysuse auto

gen var1 = 1
gen var2 = 2

local vlist var0 var1 var2 var3 mpg var4

foreach v of local vlist  {

    capture confirm variable `v'

    display "is `v' present ? " (_rc == 0)

}
```

which results in

```
is var0 present ? 0
is var1 present ? 1
is var2 present ? 1
is var3 present ? 0
is mpg present ? 1
is var4 present ? 0
```

The variable `var0` which is shown not to exist is followed `var1`, which does exist, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The Stata documentation gives [this example](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?confirm) under the help page for `confirm`. Used in conjunction with `capture`, I believe you avoid the problem with resetting `_rc`. For your purposes, simply replace the first line in the loop with `` capture confirm existence `v' ``

```
foreach v of local varlist {
                capture confirm string variable `v'
                if !_rc {
                        action for string variables
                }
                else {
                        action for numeric variables
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: It's conventional (although not compulsory) to use the name `varlist` **only** for a list of variable names. Note that adapting this example to the problem stated requires flouting the convention so that the names are not necessarily variable names.

Comment: You also need to exit the loop on the first success.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to find the first variable name present in the data in a list of potential variable names

```
sysuse auto
local vlist "var1 var2 mpg var3"

foreach var of local vlist {
    capture confirm variable `var'
    if !_rc {
        local first_present "`var'"
        continue, break // <-- stops the loop after the first present variable
    }
}

if "`first_present'" != "" {
    di as txt "The first present variable name is: " ///
       as result "`first_present'"
}
else {
    di as txt "the list contained no present variable names"
}
```